# Collada loading in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've converted a 3D model in 3ds max to a collada file, then using three.js and the collada loader im hoping to import it into my website. When doing so, the shape of the model appears but the material does not, it is blank. I have no idea why it isn't working, any help is greately appreciated. The code i have so far can be seen below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#button').click(function() {
    $('blood.DAE').toggle();
});



});
</script>

<title>Visualising Cells</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<script>

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;


var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500 );
camera.position.z = 0.16;
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
scene.add(camera);


var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width,height); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene,camera);
renderer.setClearColor("rgb(181,181,181)");

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        scene.add(light);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
        scene.add(light);



var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load('egg.DAE', function (collada) {

            object = collada.scene;
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.updateMatrix();
            scene.add(object);
            }
            );



document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
console.log(camera.position.z);
if (event.keyCode == 38) {

    if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;

    }

}

else if (event.keyCode == 40) {

    console.log("Down Arrow Pressed")

    if (camera.position.z < 0.2) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
    }

    }
}, true);

render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

object.rotation.x += 0.01;
object.rotation.y += 0.01;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
        render();


</script>

<div class="float-btn">
<button type="button">Load Red Blood Cell</button>
<button type="button">Load Egg Cell</button>
</div>

<div class="float-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 18px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h1>Visualising Microscopic Cells</h1>
</div>

<div class="instructions">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 16px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h2>Instructions</h2>
</div>

<div class="instruction-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 14px">
<p><u>Zoom In:</u> <strong>Up Arrow</strong> <br><u>Zoom Out:</u><strong>Down Arrow</strong></br></p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your material file (.jpg probably) in the same directory as the `.DAE` file? Collada format is nothing but XML that describes the model, including links to materials and such.

Comment: @JCD Yes they are in the same folder.

Comment: @JCD I moved to file locations so they were the same, added the material (.jpg) again and re-exported it as a .dae file. The shape is now fully black despite lights being in place.....

Comment: Converting 3D file formats is always a pain in the butt. If I were you I'd try running it through something like Sketchup to see if it exports something that three.js likes better. You might also try manually applying the material in three.js instead of relying on ColladaLoader.js.

Comment: I've managed to export a similar model in the same way, the only difference is that i didn't use an image wrapping. Would it stil be possible to place the model in my website if i tried using Sketchup, and if so, how would i go about doing it as i have never used Sketchup before?

Comment: I've used it in the past as an intermediary when trying to export 3D files. Import model into Sketchup, export as DAE. Results may vary. Oh, and you could try formats other than DAE. .OBJ with .MTL might work better.

Comment: Alright, I will try it tomorrow, thanks for helping. :)

Comment: Update to r74 and try colladaloader2.js

Comment: @fluffybunny What do you mean by r74?

Comment: @fluffybunny Also, how do i download colladaloader2.js?

Comment: colladaloader2 is already there in R74! just add a 2 when you include the file

Comment: Or sorry, yesterday they released a new version of 3js, release 74.